# In Google Chrome, window.open fails on csv with # symbol in it

Tags: javascript, csv, google-chrome, urlencode, window.open

```
window.open(encodeURI('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,name,color\njohn,#000000'));
```

In chrome, the previous line downloads a `csv` with this content:

```
name,color
john,
```

It seems to ignore everything after the `#` symbol.
Do you have an idea why?

ps: On Safari it seems to work well, it opens a news tab with everything in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `#` denotes the start of a location within the document.

You'll have to escape it to `%23`:

```
'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent("name,color\njohn,#000000")
```

results in `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,name%2Ccolor%0Ajohn%2C%23000000` which ought to work better.